# How to make adaptive threshold for character recognition in Android without OpenCV

Tags: android, eclipse, image-processing

I want to create threshold filter based Android for my character recognition app without OpenCV /Tesseract, etc, here is my case :

- I have an image with several characters with background and foreground color of a different
- Then when executed outputs the resulting image appears in the form of a white background and black foreground image

I've made ​​some functions in my program, the first color images are filtered by the algorithm grayscale (it's easy and it works perfectly), the second step, a grayscale image is filtered with a filter threshold algorithm, but the results did not come out as expected, as shown below

---

### [image]

Supposedly I was expecting the output is as shown below

---

[image]

And here's my source code Grayscale Function I've made :

```
      public Bitmap DoGrayscale(Bitmap BitmapColor){ 

       int w, h;
       h= BitmapColor.getHeight();
       w= BitmapColor.getWidth();    

       Bitmap BitmapGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

      int R, G, B;
      int pixel;

       for(int x = 0; x < w; ++x) {
       for(int y = 0; y < h; ++y) {

        pixel = BitmapColor.getPixel(x, y);

        R = Color.red(pixel);
        G = Color.green(pixel);
        B = Color.blue(pixel);

        R = G = B = (int)((R + G + B)/3);

        BitmapGrayscale.setPixel(x, y, Color.rgb(R, G, B));
       }
      }
      return BitmapGrayscale;

   }
```

And here's my Threshold Function source code :

```
       public Bitmap DoThreshold(Bitmap BitmapGrayscale) {

       int w, h, threshold;

       h= BitmapGrayscale.getHeight();
       w= BitmapGrayscale.getWidth();

       threshold = 128;

       Bitmap BitmapBiner = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapGrayscale);

       for(int x = 0; x < w; ++x) {
       for(int y = 0; y < h; ++y) {

               int pixel = BitmapGrayscale.getPixel(x, y);
               int gray = Color.red(pixel);

               if(gray < threshold){
                   BitmapBiner.setPixel(x, y, 0xFF000000);
               } else{
                   BitmapBiner.setPixel(x, y, 0xFFFFFFFF);
               }

           }
       }
       return BitmapBiner;
   }
```

I've been looking for various related tutorials, but none of them fit, would you help resolve this problem, please ??? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

1. for any non-white *pure* color you should expect 0 since 255/3<128, so your expectations are wrong
2. as for your results, check if your bitmap is RGBA or RGB.
3. your way of finding text is kind of idealistic since shadow, difference in lighting and noise will make non-adaptive (global) threshold less useful.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll repair my function. Is that mean it can not make the output as I had hoped ??? Thanks

Comment: You still can get the output you wanted. Just use a different formula when converting to gray.

Comment: You can, say, just convert green to gray-white and blue to gray- black instead of taking an average as in your code before: gray = (R+G+B)/3